# Find a div then replace content?

Tags: reactjs, hubspot

I have a div, that if it's on the page, I want to replace it with a different div.

Is this even possible with react?  I can find the div by searching for the div className: "end-message". I have no control over this div since its a snippet from hubspot (a form code) that it auto navigates to after the user submits the form.

```
<div type="text" ref={ref => this.myTextInput = ref} />
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, the `div` you need to replace is not rendered by React (or you can't control the logic of that rendering). So if you know some selector that allows you to get to that element, you can replace it using the DOM API `element1.replaceWith(element2);`.

This can be done roughly like this:

```
await submit()
...
setTimeout(() => {
  const elem = document.querySelector('selector');
  const newElem = document.createElement('div');
  elem.replaceWith(newElem);
}, 0)
```